# How can I make the code below more friendly to read

Tags: java

my code below is to cancel product request. A product also has sub-products. If there are errors in the validation of root or sub-products cancel the only root. If there are no errors at all cancel root and its subProducts. How can I improve the code below

```java
private void cancel(ProductCancelRe root){
    root.validateProduct(root);
    Errors errors = root.getErrors();
    List<ProductCancelRequest> list = null;

    if(root.hasSubProducts){
       list = //  some function to getProductCancelRequest for sub products
    errors.addErrors(getErrorsForSubProducts(list)
    }
    if(errors.size == 0){
        cancelProduct(root);
        if(root.hasSubProducts()){  
            for(ProductCancelRequest r : list){ 
                cancelRoot(r); // cancel subProducts also if bo errors
            }
        }
    }
    else{ 
        cancelProduct(root); // if errors cancel only root product
    }
}
```

Comment: You can split this method into few smaller methods to make it more readable. Like, a method named `validate()` that will validate and return errors if any. Another method, like `cancelProducts()` will check and cancel product. Also add proper indentation like tab, space, new line etc.

Comment: Start by applying code formatting in your IDE, either automatically or use the shortcut occasionally. There is no consistency in your formatting whatsoever.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because codereview.stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

1. Consistent indentation.
2. Either put opening brackets on the same line or the next line. Don't mix them.
3. You call `cancelProduct(root)` regardless of the conditional, so just put it at the top.

```java
private void cancel(ProductCancelRe root) {

    root.validateProduct(root);
    Errors errors = root.getErrors();
    List<ProductCancelRequest> list = null;

    if(root.hasSubProducts) {
        list = //  some function to getProductCancelRequest for sub products
        errors.addErrors(getErrorsForSubProducts(list));
    }

    cancelProduct(root);

    if(errors.size == 0 && root.hasSubProducts) {
        for(ProductCancelRequest r : list) { 
            cancelRoot(r); // cancel subProducts also if bo errors
        }
    }
}
```